# JSF 2.2: How to set UI parameter using template

Tags: jsf, facelets, omnifaces

I have a template (I removed some lines to keep code simple):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <h:head>
        <title>#{title}</title>
    </h:head>
</html>
```

And I want to set the window title with a String result from a resource bundle:

```
<ui:composition ... template="default.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="title">
        <h:outputFormat value="#{0} - Testing">
            #{mycontroller.title}
        <h:outputFormat>
    </ui:param>
</ui:composition ...>
```

But for my surprise `ui:param` doesn't support body content. I changed to Omnifaces, that supports body content.

```
<ui:composition ... template="default.xhtml">
    <o:param name="title">
        <h:outputFormat value="#{0} - Testing">
            #{mycontroller.title}
        <h:outputFormat>
    </o:param>
</ui:composition ...>
```

But doesn't works. The `#{title}` is empty in my template file. There are some way to set complex texts to my template file?